# The body may not be greater than 1000 characters

Tags: javascript, tinymce

hy guys, am working with blog site and i use tinymce for text area and it work fine but when i enter large data and i submit the form it says "The body may not be greater than 1000 characters" how can i insert data more than 1000 character in tinymce other thigs are working perfectly.
this is my script

```
<script>
        var route_prefix = "{{ url(config('lfm.prefix')) }}";
        var token = '{{Session::token()}}';
        var urlEdit = '{{route('edit')}}';
        var urlLike = '{{route('like')}}';
        var editor_config = {
            path_absolute : "",
            selector: "textarea[name=body]",
            plugins: [
                "link image"
            ],
            relative_urls: false,
            height: 329,
            file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
                var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

                var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + route_prefix + '?field_name=' + field_name;
                if (type == 'image') {
                    cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
                } else {
                    cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
                }

                tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
                    file : cmsURL,
                    title : 'Filemanager',
                    width : x * 0.8,
                    height : y * 0.8,
                    resizable : "yes",
                    close_previous : "no"
                });
            }
        };

        tinymce.init(editor_config);
    </script>
```

and my text area look like this

```
 <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" rows="50"
                          placeholder="new post">
                </textarea>
```

Comment: Show your Controller function Code?

Comment: What does your `textarea` look like?

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" rows="50"
                          placeholder="new post">
                </textarea>

Comment: can you show me the script of tinymice?

Answer (score 1):

tinymce does not have such a built-in limitation. You will have to look for other components of your system. The limitation is to be found there.